# Приведение структур (в сетевом программировании)

Tags: c, структуры, сетевое-программирование

Есть функция, которая используется в сетевом программировании, шаблон ее выглядит так:

```
int connect(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *serv_addr, int addrlen);
/* sockfd - сокет, который будет использоваться для обмена данными с сервером */
/* serv_addr содержит указатель на структуру с адресом сервера */
/* addrlen - длина этой структуры */
```

Сама структура sockaddr выглядит таким образом:

```
struct sockaddr {
    unsigned short    sa_family;    // address family, AF_xxx
    char              sa_data[14];  // 14 bytes of protocol address
};
```

для sockfd я вызываю функцию socket()

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
/* Константа AF_INET соответствует Internet-домену */
/* SOCK_STREAM обозначает передачу потока данных с предварительной установкой соединения */
/* последний аргумент функции socket()  обозначает выбор протокола, 0 - протокол выбирается по умолчанию */
```

Для домена AF_INET есть специальная структура, которая выглядит так:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short int          sin_family;  // Семейство адресов
    unsigned short int sin_port;    // Номер порта
    struct in_addr     sin_addr;    // IP-адрес
    unsigned char      sin_zero[8]; // "Дополнение" до размера структуры sockaddr
};

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;          
};
```

В своей программе я использую данную структуру таким образом:

```
int main(void){
    struct sockaddr_in test;

    test.sin_family = AF_INET;
    test.sin_port = htons( 80 ); /* преобразовывает число из порядка хоста в сетевой */
    test.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("77.37.252.217"); /* конвертирует айпи в формат long */
 }
```

Итак, теперь я вызваю функцию connect(), шаблон которой я описал ранее

```
connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&test, sizeof(test))
```

И собственно мой вопрос - разве в си можно приводить одну структуру к другой, как мы это сделали при вызове функции connect()?

p.s. Прошу прощения, что так расстянул свой вопрос, просто совесть не позволяла поставить его, ничего не объяснив.

p.s.2 Как вы поняли, я сейчас изучаю сетевое программирование, поэтому, если у вас есть соответствующая литература, где все доступно и понятно объяснено, то прошу указать такую в комментариях (на русском или на английском - без разницы). Заранее спасибо

Comment: Здесь не приводится одна структура к другой. Функция `connect` ожидает 2 параметром указатель на структуру `sockaddr`, поэтому от локальной переменной `test` берется адрес, это, по сути, void*, и приводится к указателю на структуру sockaddr

Comment: Да, в C можно приводить что угодно к чему угодно. адреса они всегда одинаковы, они просто указывают на область в памяти, где лежат данные. А что там за данные это дело десятое, главное что бы принимающая функция была готова интерпретировать значение по адресу так как надо

Comment: Это нормальная практика в Си. Конечно, для красоты можно указатели в union завернуть, но это опционально. А так то... Физически функция в получает адрес. У всех этих структур одинаковое первое поле, указывающее на формат структуры. А уже внутри функционала будет работать соответствующая логика, в зависимости от формата.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас в коде нет приведения одной структуры к другой, а есть явное приведение *указателя* на один тип структуры к *указателю* на другой тип структуры. В самом приведении указателей ничего необычного нет: при помощи явного приведения типа в языке С вы можете приводить друг к другу указатели на любые типы данных (см. однако, замечание @wololo в комментариях). А вот что будет происходит после такого приведения - отдельная тема.

Затем, через посредство такого приведения, внутри функции `connect` будет делаться *переинтерпретация* памяти занимаемой структурой типа `struct sockaddr_in` как представление структуры типа `struct sockaddr`. Этот прием называется type punning. Изначальное поле (изначальный набор полей) у этих структур совпадает, на чем и держится эта попытка переинтерпретации.

В языке С такие переинтерпретации приводят к неопределенному поведению (нарушение правил strict aliasing), за исключением ряда языковых контекстов, в которых это специально разрешено. В частности, разрешается переинтерпретация через `union` и переинтерпретация как массив `unsigned char`. Ваш случай в этот список не входит. Ваш код - популярный "грязный хак", который с точки зрения языка С неработоспособен. А далее уже идут лишь особенности конкретных реализаций, в которых это может работать, но к языку С это уже никакого отношения не имеет.

Трюк этот со структурами `struct sockaddr_in` и `struct sockaddr` применяется уже очень давно и является, в некотором смысле, "священной коровой" сетевого программирования. Так что работать он будет. Но это не более чем отголосок тех замшелых достандартных времен, когда язык С был чем-то вроде "ассемблера" и никто не задумывался о подобных вопросах.

Comment: " в языке С вы можете приводить друг к другу указатели на любые типы данных". Даже простое приведение в общем случае опасно: "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."